# Identity user object is not mapped to another object - entity framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, .net-core, asp.net-identity

So I have the .NET Core app made with ASP.Identity and EntityFramework with code first approach.
My AppUser class:

```
public class AppUser : IdentityUser<string>
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateJoined { get; set; }
}
```

Then I have the Notice.cs class with AppUser attached

```
    public class Notice
{
    //... some other props
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public DateTime DatePosted { get; set; }
    public AppUser AppUser { get; set; }
}
```

And my applicationDbContext

```
 public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<AppUser, Role, string>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) 
        : base(options)
    {

    }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Entity<Notice>()
            .Property(p => p.NoticeId)
            .ValueGeneratedOnAdd();

        builder.Entity<AppUser>()
            .Property(p => p.Id)
            .ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
        builder.Entity<Role>()
            .Property(p => p.Id)
            .ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
    }
    public DbSet<Notice> Notices { get; set; }
}
```

After seeding notices into database and assigning users to them I am not able to access AppUser property.
I have looked into database and I can see that Notices table has appropriate AppUserId column with correct Ids. However every time I try to access AppUser property of Notice from database context it is always null. How can i fix it? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't show how are you accessing `AppUser` from a `Notice`, if it is similar to this:

```
var notice = dbContext.Notices
                 .First(n => n.NoticeId == id); // get the notice without AppUser
```

then the `notice.AppUser` will be `null`, because you're not explicitly including that property to be joined to the result.

You can achieve that like this:

```
var notice = dbContext.Notices
                 .Include(n => n.AppUser)
                 .First(n => n.NoticeId == id); // get the notice with AppUser
```

Comment: Alright, I was doing it via repository, which indeed did not join the property. Its clear to me know, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You have created a one-way relationship that Entity Framework doesn’t know how to handle. I’m assuming if you look into the database you will not see a foreign key on the tables.

To your AppUser class, try adding:

```
Public ICollection<Notice> Notices { get; set; }
```

This should allow entity framework to recognize both sides of the relationship.

I’m assuming each app user may have many notices.

Comment: I have tried adding it to AppUser class, then when I have tried to do migration he didnt see any changes in the db structure. So I have deleted whole db and migrations and started with initial migration. And still I'm not able to access AppUser from Notice entity. The AppUserId foreign key is in the Notice table and it is correctly assigned - same as before :/